# Expected Method Body Error?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I keep on getting the "Expected Method Body" error when i try to run my app on Xcode. The bolded place is the place where I got the error. HELP!!! One More thing, I keep on getting a error saying "incomplete implementation" on the "@implementation SoundnoardFirstViewController" part. HELP!! thanks

```
#import "SoundnoardFirstViewController.h"

@interface SoundnoardFirstViewController ()

@end

@implementation SoundnoardFirstViewController

-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1

**-(IBAction)PlaySound2:(id)sender2**

-(IBAction)PlaySound3:(id)sender3

-(IBAction)PlaySound4:(id)sender4

-(IBAction)PlaySound5:(id)sender5

-(IBAction)PlaySound6:(id)sender6

(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender { 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"This is the name of the clip", CFSTR ("sound file type"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
 }

-(IBAction)PlaySound2:(id)sender2:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"DoYouHave?", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)PlaySound3:(id)sender3:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"Hello", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}

-(IBAction)PlaySound4:(id)sender4:(id)sender {
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"SoupBetter?", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
```

Comment: your method declaration is different from from your implementation header.use  this `-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1` instead of `-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender` and add `-` before `(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

declare the private methods inside the `SoundnoardFirstViewController ()`

```
@interface SoundnoardFirstViewController ()

  //declare the private methods here

@end
```

**Example:**

```
#import "SoundnoardFirstViewController.h"

@interface SoundnoardFirstViewController ()

-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender;
-(IBAction)PlaySound2:(id)sender2:(id)sender

@end

@implementation SoundnoardFirstViewController

-(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender { 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"This is the name of the clip", CFSTR ("sound file type"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
 }

-(IBAction)PlaySound2:(id)sender2:(id)sender{ 
    CFBundleRef mainBundle = CFBundleGetMainBundle();
    CFURLRef soundFileURLRef;
    soundFileURLRef = CFBundleCopyResourceURL(mainBundle, (CFStringRef) @"DoYouHave?", CFSTR ("mp3"), NULL);
    UInt32 soundID;
    AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID(soundFileURLRef, &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `-` before the implementation of sender` on the line:

```
(IBAction)PlaySound1:(id)sender1:(id)sender {
```